# annotation to resolve all error for unimplemented method of interface?

Tags: java, interface, annotations

I am having an interface which is having more than 20 method but only few make sense for my need. I have implemented the required method.

I don't want to write code just as null body. Is there any annotation or any way by which i can bypass this and avoid writing blank body?

Thanks.
Praveen

Comment: I don't think there is a such way, But you can write all blank body methods using eclipse on a click only.

Comment: Are you sure that's only one interface if things that are implementing it only need a few of them? You could `throw new UnsupportedOperationException();` which annotates it in the docs and is better IMHO than blank bodies. What happens when you have a return of an object or primitive?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to make every unimplemented method throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. This is what `Collections.unmodifiableList()` does so that it can return a `List` but you can't use `add()` on it.

For example:

```
@Override
public void notNeeded() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Another option is to consider if it really makes sense to implement such interface. Instead, you could create a smaller, more specialized interface that fits your use case better. If you can modify the current interface, make it extend the new one so you don't get repeated code.

For example, suppose you have `BigInterface` which declares some methods that you don't want to implement in your class `MyClass`:

```
interface BigInterface {
    void notNeeded();
    int alsoNotNeeded();

    boolean neededMethod();
}
```

You can extract only the methods you need and create a new interface:

```
interface SmallInterface {
    boolean neededMethod();
}
```

Then make `BigInterface` extend `SmallInterface`, so those classes that implement `BigInterface` keep working as usual:

```
interface BigInterface extends SmallInterface {
    void notNeeded();
    int alsoNotNeeded();
}
```

And make `MyClass` implement `SmallInterface` only:

```
class MyClass implements SmallInterface {
    @Override
    public boolean neededMethod() {
        return true;
    }
}
```